# Type Error in Code

Tags: excel, vba

Have defined Z and LT as Long

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NORMSINV(RC[-1])"    
Z = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=VLOOKUP($B$1,Sheet3!$A$74:$D$97,4,FALSE)"

LT = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" + Z + "*RC[-2]*SQRT(" + LT + ")"
```

This line is giving Type error

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace  '+' with & this is how concatenate works in VBA

Comment: Hey Can you also help me with the datatype we use for Real Numbers